# can't find email string using Find method in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find the address of the cell containing a specific email address.  here's my code:

```
Function find_email(range_input As Range) As String

    Dim item_input As String
    item_input = "test@test.com"

    Dim found_range As Range

    With Worksheets("test_sheet").range_input

        Set found_range = .Find(What:=item_input, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    End With
    find_email = found_range.Address

End Function
```

**EDIT post answer 1**

I've taken the suggestion made in answer #1 and changed to code to be:

```
Public Function find_email(range_input As Range, string_input As String, collumn_offsett As Integer) As String

    Dim found_range As Range

    With Worksheets("test_sheet").Range(range_input.Address)
        Set found_range = .Find(What:=string_input, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    End With

    Dim output_range As Range
    Set output_range = found_range.Offset(0, collumn_offsett)
    find_email = output_range

End Function

Sub test_email_find_code()
    Debug.Print find_email(Range("f1:f7"), "test@test.com", -3)
End Sub
```

The sub `test_email_find_code` works great.  When I try to use function `find_email` in a cell, however, it doesn't work.  I don't really understand how to research this.  Do I have to adjust the range input somehow?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It works when I tested it. Are you sure you are referencing the correct objects? (e.g. worksheet name)

Answer (score 1):

To make it work like you have written you'll need to change the With line like this:

```
With Worksheets("test_sheet").Range(range_input.Address)
```

---

Here's your full code located in a separate module:

```
Public Function find_email(range_input As Range) As String
    Dim item_input As String
    item_input = "test@test.com"

    Dim found_range As Range

    With Worksheets("test_sheet").Range(range_input.Address)
        Set found_range = .Find(What:=item_input, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    End With
    find_email = found_range.Address
End Function
```

---

You can test it with another sub like this:

```
Sub findEmail()
    Debug.Print find_email(Range("A1:D100"))
End Sub
```

---

Or use an in-cell function like this:

```
=find_email(A1:D100)
```

---

Result depends on the answer, I used cell C4 so the result was `$C$4`

Comment: It prints the answer in the immediate window, but not in the cell.

Comment: Yep, the debug.print was just for testing the function since I don't know what your doing with the result.  That's why I inculded an in cell example too.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer and it seems to work in one case, but I can't get it to work in my spreadsheet as a function.  I added an edit to my question to try to make in clear.

Comment: Your code in the edit looks good.  I entered this formula in cell A1: `=find_email(F1:F7,"test@test.com",-3)` and got the correct result which was the value from column C on the matching row of email in col F.  Your code should be in a separate module and not in the sheet behind.  If that doesn't help, put a break point at the start of your function and then hit enter in the cell with the formula.  This will allow you to step thru your code and see what errors are encountered.